# Unable to get to window.electronAPI in a new window

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

when opening new window from a renderer, the script in my new HTML window returns **undefined** for **`window.electronAPI`** , while all my other render files are able to call it just fine, made me think that the new window is not inheriting the settings on the original (main.js) window settings, but according to docs, that is not the case. (Been all over the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/window-open) several times)

**main.js** config:

```
const createWindow = () => {
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
  }
})

win.loadFile('index.html')}
```

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(selector)
      if (element) element.innerText = text
    }

    for (const dependency of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
      replaceText(${dependency}-version, process.versions[dependency])
    }
  })
  contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
    setTitle: (title) => ipcRenderer.send('set-title', title),
    setPage: (pg) => ipcRenderer.send('set-pg', pg),
    getVehicleDetailsVIN: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('get-veh-detail-vin'),

  })
```

opening the new window from another render process like so:

```
 window.open('./myPage.html');
```

The window opens fine, and the html is loaded, now from the render script of myPage.html I am calling:

```js
        const vin =  window.electronAPI.getVehicleDetailsVIN() || '';
        console.log("vehicledetail vin "+vin)
```

console will throw:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVehicleDetailsVIN')
```

**What was tried to resolve**

Going through potential solutions posted, reading document I tried several things, but perhaps the highlights are two tries, both didn't work:

**tried passing the preload into the open()**:

```
 window.open('./myPage.html', '_blank', 'top=500,left=200, nodeIntegration=true,preload="../../preload.js"');
```

This had no effect, not sure if it is consuming these properties anyway because for example setting the top/width property to a small number like 50 instead of 500 renders the same page dimensions regardless.

**Also tried adding `setWindowOpenHandler` to main.js window config:**

```js
    const createWindow = () => {
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
  }
})
 // add setWindowOpenHandler to manually enter preload.js path for the new window
win.loadFile('index.html')
 win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(() => {
      return {
        action: 'allow',
        overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
          webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
          }
        }
      }
    })}
```

But this try failed too, in this try the app almost stops altogether, when opening the new window with this config, the dev tools freeze and both the new and parent windows contents go blank white, and the console throws errors:

[image]

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe [33160]: ..\..\third_party\electron_node\src\api\callback.cc:74: Assertion `(Environment::GetCurrent(isolate)) == (env)' failed.
 1: 00007FF7DC628A36 node::SetTracingController+80086
 2: 00007FF7DC62870C node::SetTracingController+79276
 3: 00007FF7DC69D353 node::CallbackScope::CallbackScope+499
 4: 00007FF7DC69D19D node::CallbackScope::CallbackScope+61
```

Comment: what's up with those errors in the console? Should you fix those?

Comment: these are development errors mostly related to image src files  i intentionally left them to clean later after the app is done, they do not affect my work, anyway I found a work around to my problem which I will post shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around, not exactly what i wanted because it comes with cost, but it is working. I thought I should post the work around for others to use in the future since I found no solutions to my problem.

The core of the problem is that `preload.js` is not loaded in the newly opened window and therefore I can not use the functions inside, I tried literally tens of different things in a span of three days with no solution.

Then I found couple people floating the idea of opening the new window not with a simple `window.open()` JS function , but a new electron window using `BrowserWindow` , in other words, open the new window from `main.js` rather than a renderer and Also open it as a BrowserWindow object exactly the same way the original (parent) window is opened, using the same settings, the only trick/addition is to add parent attribute and add the parent window object (of type BrowserWindow ) as parent. This way the newly opened window will defiantly have the preload loaded into it no matter what.

Triggering that request to main.js will be done using ipcRenderer function defined in preload.js (just like the other functions), then this will be handled in `main.js` using `ipcMain` by triggering my `createChildWindow` function.

```js
  function createChildWindow(data) {
    var childOpened=false;
    //i do not want child window opened more than once at a time, so i prevent future requests from creating more windows if one is already open
    BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().forEach(function (win) {
      console.log("window id:"+win.id);
      //the main/parent window will always have id of 1, so I know that is the main
      if (win.id > 1) {
       childOpened=true;
      }
     })
    console.log("child opened ="+childOpened);
    if(!childOpened){
      const childWin = new BrowserWindow({
       width: 800,
       height: 600,
       webPreferences: {
         nodeIntegration: true,
         enableRemoteModule: true,
         contextBridge: true,
         nativeWindowOpen: true,
         nodeIntegrationInSubFrames: true,
         parent:win, //this is the main app window created above looks something like this: win = new BrowserWindow({... make sure it is declared globally to be able to access it here
         preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
       }
     })
     childWin.loadFile(data.url)
    }//end if

    else{
      console.log("child window opened already");
    }
  }
```

**The cost of this approach**

I know of two costs for giving up on `window.open()` in favor of this method:

1. `window.open()` to me seemed to be lightweight, not loaded with all kinds of stuff, because (i might be wrong) but i do believe that using this methods adds so much stuff to my window, I feel that it is slower then when I used `window.open()` to open the page.
2. Using `window.open()` closes the opened window automatically if you close the parent window (which is what we want in most cases, you don't want to forget a window with private information after you exit the app main window), while using electron's `BrowserWindow` keeps the child window open even if parent window is closed, so i need more work to deal with this.

I hope this answer is useful to others in the future.

Further reading on this approach: [ElectronJS Parent-Child Windows](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#parent-and-child-windows)

Comment: weird, fwiw, in my case, I do intercept window.open via the setWindowOpenHandler and set a preload script in there, and it seems to work. Maybe my version of platform is different from yours, and there are some weird behavior differences there.

Answer (score 0):

As @pushkin stated in comments, I think `setWindowOpenHandler` is the right way to go. Recently I upgraded Electron from v12 to v22 and I had to replicate all webpreferences for the child window in the open handler, not only the preload script. So you should try to explicitly give `nodeIntegration` and other attributes as you do in the main window. That's worked for me.